# Text overlays the box in mobile view, how can i implement Media Query in my Code?

Tags: html, css, mpmediaquery

I tried different Ways to implement Media Query or other Options to to adjust the Size of the Font to fit the View to different Devices but I'm an absolute Beginner who threw together a few Codesnippets. Please help me to adjust the Code so that it works.

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  height: 00vh;
  justify-content: center;
   margin: 0;
}

.doi_tuong{
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #121212;
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 16px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, -10px -10px 20px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, -8px -8px 12px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  height: 70px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 0rem;
  padding: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


.doi_tuong:hover {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
}

.text-doi_ {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="doi_tuong"
             <p><font color="white" style="font-size:25px">   Lorem et ipsum Lorem et ipsum</font></p>
         </body>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can do responsiveness using https://getbootstrap.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `height: 00vh;` from `<body>` tag to fix your issue. Replace the below code with yours.

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;` are pointless if `flex` is removed.

Comment: then you should remove the height from the body tag depending on what he is trying to do.

Comment: Hey Guys, thank you very much for your Help. The Problem ist the same as bevor because the Text does not fit in Media or Tablet version in to the Box. The Container change the Size to small and the Text stays the same size over the Container.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in why it's not working on desktop or mobile is because you had invalid markup and you have `height: 00vh;` on your `body` element. Remove that and it should be good. I also added an example media query in your CSS.

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.doi_tuong {
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #121212;
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 16px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, -10px -10px 20px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, -8px -8px 12px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  height: 70px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 0rem;
  padding: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.doi_tuong:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
}

.text-doi_ {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* added */

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .doi_tuong {
    margin-top: 3rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="doi_tuong">
  <p style="font-size:25px; color: white;"> Lorem et ipsum Lorem et ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: **Side note:** the `transition` only needs to be on the element with the `transform` so it would only be `.doi_tuong` and not `.doi_tuong:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.doi_tuong{
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #121212;
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 16px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, -10px -10px 20px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, -8px -8px 12px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 4rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

}

.doi_tuong:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).